# VB.NET Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int error

Tags: sql, vb.net, datetime, select, where-clause

I am trying to display records from a table named **staffpresentee** from a database using the where clause...

i am using visual studio 2010...

the table design is as follows-

```
.......fieldname..................datatype........allownull
1......staff_id (fk).............numeric(18,0)......yes
2.......date........................date.............no
3......present.....................char(1)..........yes
```

Note that the type of the 2nd field is date and not datetime...

I want to display all records from the table that have today's date int the 'date' field...
My current query is-

```
cmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("select * from staffpresentee where date=" & Date.Now.Date, cn)
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
```

for `dr = cmd.ExecuteReader` i get the error

> "Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int"

i tried the `select * from staffpresentee` query without the where clause it runs correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this-

```
cmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("select * from staffpresentee where [date]=@dt", cn)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", DateTime.Now.Date)
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the date value in sigle quotes maybe.

```
cmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("select * from staffpresentee where date='" & _
                                                      Date.Now.Date & "'", cn)
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
```

Comment: It helps... atleast i got past the `dr=cmd.ExecuteReader` line... <br>
but on the next line I have a condition

    `if dr.read() then
         my condition
    end if`

on the if statement line, now the error says-<br>
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Never mind i found the answer...
i did the following-
        `cmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("select * from staffpresentee where [date]=@dt", cn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", DateTime.Now.Date)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader`